# Fastest Way to Determine if Character Belongs to a Set of Known Characters C++

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, containers, unordered-set

Given any character, what's the fastest way for me to determine if that character belongs to a set (not the container-type) of known characters.

In other words, what's the fastest elegant way to implement the conditional:
    `char c = 'a';`
    `if(c == ch1 || c == ch2 || c == ch3 ...) // Do something...`

Is there an STL container (I'm thinking it might be unordered_set?) that I can just pass the character as a key to and it'll return true if the key exists?

Anything with an O(1) lookup time will work for me.

Comment: put `ch1` `ch2` and `ch3` in a `std::unordered_set<char>` then test if c is in it. it's o(1) time lookups. O(m) memory with m = number of characters in your set. The rest is just (ugly and stupid) premature optimization. This is what std::set are for.

Comment: Be careful because these fancy data structures may cause dynamic memory allocations which end up slower than a regular if statement.

Comment: You can try making them global variables (eg `static const`) in a function to save construction costs.

Comment: @FélixCantournet - ironically, as the tests below indicate, `std::set` is the worst possible solution to the problem.

Comment: @ddriver the `std::unordered_set` is 4 times slower to run, 10 times faster to type and get right. 10 times simpler to read. But most importantly and I quote the OP : "Anything with an O(1) lookup time will work for me". Enough said.

Comment: In the title he asks about "fastest way" but then settles for O(1) which is quite slow relative to the fastest. That's an oxymoron there. BTW the set also takes considerably longer to initialize before it is ready for lookup.

Comment: Not to mention that `set` has a O(log2(size)) access and not O(1).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I went a little further and wrote two versions, one based on a lookup array, the other on a set using an underlying hash.

```
class CharLookup {
public:
  CharLookup(const std::string & set) : lookup(*std::max_element(set.begin(), set.end()) + 1) {
    for ( auto c : set) lookup[c] = true;
  }
  inline bool has(const unsigned char c) const {
    return c > lookup.size() ? false : lookup[c];
  }
private:
  std::vector<bool> lookup;
};

class CharSet {
public:
  CharSet(const std::string & cset) {
    for ( auto c : cset) set.insert(c);
  }
  inline bool has(const unsigned char c) const {
    return set.contains(c);
  }
private:
  QSet<unsigned char> set;
};
```

Then wrote a little benchmark, added a few more containers for the sake of comparison. Lower is better, the data points are for "character set size / text size":

[image]

Seems like for short char sets and text, `std::string::find_first_of` is fastest, even faster than using a lookup array, but quickly dwindles as the test size increases. `std::vector<bool>` seems like the "golden mean", `QBitArray` probably has a little different implementation because it pulls ahead as the test size increases, at the largest test `QVector<bool>` is fastest, presumably because it doesn't have the overhead of bit access. The two hash sets are close, trading places, last and least there is the `std::set`.

Tested on an i7-3770k Win7 x64 box, using MinGW 4.9.1 x32 with -O3.

Comment: QSet is a hash-table (http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qset.html) based container whereas std::set is often implemented as a red-black tree. A RB tree has O(log n) complexity which is slower than O(1) for a hash-table. Comparing against std::unordered_set would have been a fairer comparison.

Comment: @PeterR - yes, I added a bunch of others, seems like unordered_set is on par with QSet.

Comment: Nice graph, I'm impressed by the performance of the bit vectors.

Answer (score 9):

You could create an array of booleans and assign the value `true` for each character in wanted set. For example if your wanted set consists of `'a', 'd', 'e'`:

```
bool array[256] = {false};
array['a'] = true;
array['d'] = true;
array['e'] = true;
```

and then you can check a character `c`:

```
if (array[c]) ...
```

We could also use a bitset for this purpose:

```
std::bitset<256> b;
b.set('a');
b.set('d');
b.set('e');
```

and checking as:

```
if (b.test(c)) ...
```

Comment: A bitset would be more cache friendly at the expense of more CPU cycles.

Comment: @RonTang: It's actually very simple to achieve: use `std::vector<bool>` instead of an array.

Comment: On a side note, we live in Unicode times now, so it will need 8k worth of bits for the lookup.

Comment: I'm wondering if bitset and vector<bool> the performance is better?

Comment: vector of bool is usually implemented as a bitset, only its dynamic while the bitset is a static construct, in the case of a small bitset it might be faster if it fits in a register, but for long sequences I think performance will be comparable.

Comment: @ddriver: 1,114,112 bits to be exact, or 136 KiB.

Comment: @ddriver: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point: "...Unicode comprises 1,114,112 code points in the range [0] to [0x10FFFF]"

Comment: @ddriver None of the other solutions work with unicode characters; Why single out this answer?

Comment: @Cubic - it was the single answer at the time.

Answer (score 4):

Keep it simple.

```
static const char my_chars[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
if (std::find(std::begin(my_chars), std::end(my_chars), char_to_test))
```

The lookup is linear, but that doesn't tell the whole story. Other data structures may give constant lookup, but the constant can be higher than the maximum "linear" value! If search times with increasing n are O(1) = (100, 100, 100) and O(n) = (10, 20, 30), then you can see that O(n) is faster than O(1) for these small n.

As there are only a small number of characters, I would be very surprised if the simple linear search measures slower than the alternatives in some *real* code.

If you ensure the array is sorted, you can also try `std::binary_search`. I don't know if it will be faster or slower for a small number of values.

As always, measure to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

Typically this kind of test is not isolated, i.e. you don't just have

```
if(c==ch1 || c==ch2 || c=ch3 ) { ... }
```

But

```
if(c==ch1 || c==ch2 || c=ch3 ) {
    handle_type_a(c);
}
else if(c==ch4 || c==ch5 || c=ch6 ) {
    handle_type_b(c);
}    
else if(c==ch7 || c==ch8 || c=ch9 ) {
    handle_type_c(c);
}

if(c==ch4 || c==ch6 || c=ch7 ) {
    handle_magic(c);
}
```

Optimising each of the `if` statements is possibly less efficient than considering all these parts at once. What this kind of structure usually means is that groups of characters are being considered equivalent in some ways - and that is what we might want to express in the code.

In this case, I'd build up a character traits array that contains the character type information.

```
// First 2 bits contains the "type" of the character
static const unsigned char CHAR_TYPE_BITS = 3;
static const unsigned char CHAR_TYPE_A = 0;  
static const unsigned char CHAR_TYPE_B = 1;
static const unsigned char CHAR_TYPE_C = 2;
// Bit 3 contains whether the character is magic
static const unsigned char CHAR_IS_MAGIC = 4;

static const unsigned char[256] char_traits = {
  ...,
  CHAR_TYPE_A, CHAR_TYPE_B | CHAR_IS_MAGIC ...
  ...
}

static inline unsigned char get_character_type(char c) {
  return char_traits[(unsigned char)c] & CHAR_TYPE_BITS;
}

static inline boolean is_character_magic(char c) {
 return (char_traits[(unsigned char)c] & CHAR_IS_MAGIC) == CHAR_IS_MAGIC;
}
```

Now your conditions become

```
switch(get_character_type(c)) { 
 case CHAR_TYPE_A:
    handle_type_a(c);
    break;
 case CHAR_TYPE_B:
    handle_type_b(c);
    break;
 case CHAR_TYPE_C:
    handle_type_c(c);
    break;
}

if(is_character_magic(c)) {
  handle_magic(c);
}
```

I'd usually extract the `char_traits` variable into its own include, and generate that include using a simple program too. This keeps things easy to change going forwards.

Answer (score 1):

Such a function is available in C and C++. I guess it is also a relative fast function. I've included a C++ example application that must detect whether a character is a separator.

```
#include <cstring>

bool is_separator(char c)
{
    return std::strchr(" \f\t\v\r\n\\+-=()", c); // this includes \0!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking your single character against a string of the characters you want to compare against?

**[std::string::find_first_of()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/)**

Comment: That would be the obvious solution.
What I'm going for -- in the interest of extremely efficient code -- is something that will have a constant lookup time, no matter how large the list of characters may be.
I'm under the impression that using a hash table is the best way, but I'm not certain how to implement it in the simplest way possible.

Comment: Sorry, hit enter too soon.

Comment: @AlexanderEden - for large collections hash will be faster, but they will have to be "sufficiently large". You best profile to determine what is best suited for the range of your requirements. What kind of charset would that be...

Comment: `std::string mychars="abc"; mychars.find(c) != std::string::npos;` will also work. (`find_first_of` with that prototype is identical. I don't know why both exist.)