# stl hashtable [unordered map] look up performance with size

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I have a very basic question regarding time complexity of hash map with the growth in size. Ideally the look up time should be constant O(1).

Does the time complexity for look up remains constant with growth in the size of the hash table ?

Let me also quote the reason for asking this. I have a application where in i store millions of entries in an unordered map. As the size grows, the application takes longer times in look up.

Comment: I see context, but no question ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29068130/fastest-way-to-determine-if-character-belongs-to-a-set-of-known-characters-c/29068727#29068727

Answer (score 0):

> As the size grows, the application takes longer times in look up.

Iterate over all the buckets and output bucket sizes. Ideal bucket size is 0 and 1. Bigger buckets sizes may indicate that the hash function you use is sub-optimal in that it causes hash collisions.